# Как изменить следующий запланированный номер PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: mysql, sql

Допустим были дебаговые добавления, далее желается чтобы id пошёл с числа выбранного.

Comment: Предлагаю посмотреть в сторону данного вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230006/renumber-primary-key

Comment: Но зачем? Значение `primary key` не должно нести никакого сакрального смысла, это просто уникальный `id` и всё, его эстетика (например, отсутствие пропусков в нумерации) не играет никакого значения.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = <выбранное число>`